# Disable gatekeeper notarisation check without disabling SIP

Tags: sip, gatekeeper, notarization

I am running into [this issue](https://sigpipe.macromates.com/2020/macos-catalina-slow-by-design/) where MacOS does security checks on new executables *over the network*. This introduces a significant delay when first running a new executable. It's very annoying when developing code because the executables are almost always new.

Is there any way to disable this check *without disabling SIP*?

Answer (score 2):

Aha, I didn't find a way to disable it system-wide for all apps, but you can disable it for specific apps in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Developer Tools

[image: screw you Apple]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Apple Mobile File Integrity by restarting your Mac into Recovery mode (hold Cmd-R while booting), and then run the following commands in a Terminal:

```
csrutil disable
nvram boot-args="amfi_get_out_of_my_way=0x1"
```

Then reboot your Mac and the delays should be gone.